# FileOutputStream write does not raise exception when file has been deleted?

Tags: android, file-io

I use `FileOutputStream fos` to create/append  and write to a debug file in a separate thread:

```
   fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);
    if (!outputFile.exists()) {
    outputFile.createNewFile();
    }
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
```

This code keeps beeing called in a loop while the user might clear=delete the file anytime from another thread to start logging the debug output anew.

Now I am really surprised that when the file is beeing deleted this code runs through without raising any exceptions BUT nothing happens. ie the file is not beeing recreated nor is anything written anmore. All the "writes" are just lost.

Do I really have to check manually all the time whether the file has been deleted in the meanwhile myself before calling `fos.write` each time?

If the exception would work like expected, ie when writing to a deleted file, it would be just easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is totally OS dependent. On Windows, you wouldn't be *able* to delete the file; but on UNIX-like systems, this is just how it works, independent of programming language. Given that a file can have multiple links which can be deleted independently, you should understand why this behavior makes sense. And it fact, it leads to easier and cleaner behavior than exploding when a file is deleted would.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer - however I am not sure I really agree on "And it fact, it leads to easier and cleaner behavior than exploding when a file is deleted would." Having a clean exception to handle this case is not really "exploding". Nevertheless - thanks alot for making this clear - so I have to check if the file exists before each single write to the file. Did I understand you correctly then?

Comment: @user387184 Try Windows development sometimes ... and you'll like *IX filesystem semantics ;-) Anyway, do not check before a write. Only on an open (which is "built-in" depending on mode). If someone unlinks the file ("deletes it"), hopefully they had a reason... a better way to "clear" the file would be to truncate it, perhaps.

Comment: In this case I have to check before each write if the file still exists, since it's a debug loop with many outputs and the user my start anew at any stage, forgetting about all the previous debug output lines - Anyway it is really fast and no issue at all. Thanks again for making this cristall clear! That's why I love SO!